VBA JsonConverter.ParseJson Parse Jason giving me error Type Mismatch
I have below Json value in string groupsjasontext and I like to parse id, members.value, roles.value using JsonConverter.ParseJson. How will I do it ? I tried to show via messagebox for id field and I am getting error Type Mismatch
    Set JsonData = JsonConverter.ParseJson(groupsjasontext)
    tempName = JsonData("id")(0)
    MsgBox (tempName)

    {
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
  ],
  "totalResults": 3,
  "startIndex": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 3,
  "Resources": [
    {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group",
        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters"
      ],
      "id": "d3094970-ce7e-4794-b9e2-f84817b7c820",
      "meta": {
        "resourceType": "Group",
        "created": "2024-05-21T17:53:06.808Z",
        "lastModified": "2024-05-21T17:53:06.808Z",
        "location": "/api/v1/scim2/Groups/d3094970-ce7e-4794-b9e2-f84817b7c820"
      },
      "displayName": "AHI_VW_ALL_REGION",
      "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters": {
        "description": "View Mode ALL REGION"
      }
    },
    {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group",
        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles",
        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters"
      ],
      "id": "bef561ee-5a1e-420e-a1e\n4-4f624c96af6e",
      "meta": {
        "resourceType": "Group",
        "created": "2024-07-25T14:17:53.215Z",
        "lastModified": "2024-08-01T14:31:29.632Z",
        "location": "/api/v1/scim2/Groups/bef561ee-5a1e-420e-a1e4-4f624c96af6e"
      },
      "displayName": "TEAM_TEST",
      "members": [
        {
          "value": "f27dcbb9-df9a-46b2-b23a-3b35d5a8bdff",
          "type": "User",
          "display": "Test_FirstName1 TEST_Familyname1",
          "$ref": "/api/v1/scim2/Users/f27dcbb9-df9a-46b2-b23a-3b35d5a8bdff"
        }
      ],
      "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles": {
        "roles": [
          {
            "value": "PROFILE:t.4:VIEW_USER",
            "display": "VIEW_USER"
          }
        ]
      },
      "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters": {
        "description": "Team Test"
      }
    },
    {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group",
        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters"
      ],
      "id": "1edd9227-c8de-486e-93f6-69396524c792",
      "meta": {
        "resourceType": "Group",
        "created": "2024-05-21T17:51:49.808Z",
        "lastModified": "2024-05-21T17:53:06.121Z",
        "location": "/api/v1/scim2/Groups/1edd9227-c8de-486e-93f6-69396524c792"
      },
      "displayName": "AHI_VW_EURAM\n",
      "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters": {
        "description": "View mode EURAM"
      }
    }
  ]
}


MsgBox JsonData("id") the id key is just a single value, not a collection/array.

Note that parentheses should not be included in MsgBox (tempName). Parentheses would be used if you were assigning the return value to a variable, e.g. result = MsgBox(tempName).

I have found it far easier to specifically access different parts of a JSON object individually at each step. This helped to avoid most of the issues and confusion between the different objects (Dictionaries and Collections). I use this reference all the time, it's proved to be a big help.
So based on that advice, and using the linked reference, I came up with the test code below to show how to access different parts of your JSON structure and perform loops when it's appropriate.
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim strJSON As String
    strJSON = GetJSONString
    
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = ParseJson(strJSON)
    
    Dim resources As Collection
    Set resources = GetCollection(json, "Resources")
    
    Dim junk As Collection
    Set junk = GetCollection(json, "junk")
    
    Dim resource As Dictionary
    For Each resource In resources
        Debug.Print "----- Resource:"
        Dim schemas As Collection
        Set schemas = GetCollection(resource, "schemas")
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To schemas.Count
            Debug.Print "   Schema(" & i & ") = " & schemas(i)
        Next i
        
        Dim id As String
        id = resource("id")
        
        Dim meta As Dictionary
        Set meta = GetDictionary(resource, "meta")
        If Not meta Is Nothing Then
            Dim metaEntry As Variant
            For Each metaEntry In meta
                Debug.Print "   Meta Entry: " & metaEntry & " = " & meta(metaEntry)
            Next metaEntry
        End If
        
        Dim displayName As String
        displayName = resource("displayName")
        
        Dim members As Collection
        Set members = GetCollection(resource, "members")
        If Not members Is Nothing Then
            Dim member As Variant
            Debug.Print "   member count = " & members.Count
            For i = 1 To members.Count
                Dim memberEntry As Dictionary
                Set memberEntry = members(i)
                Dim entryKey As Variant
                For Each entryKey In memberEntry
                    Debug.Print "   For member(" & i & "): " & entryKey & " = " & memberEntry(entryKey)
                Next entryKey
            Next i
        End If
    Next resource
End Sub

Function GetCollection(ByRef jsonObj As Object, ByVal entryName As String) As Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetCollection = jsonObj(entryName)
    If GetCollection Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "The requested object " & entryName & " does not exist in the referenced Collection"
    End If
End Function

Function GetDictionary(ByRef jsonObj As Object, ByVal entryName As String) As Dictionary
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetDictionary = jsonObj(entryName)
    If GetDictionary Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "The requested object " & entryName & " does not exist in the referenced Dictionary"
    End If
End Function

Function GetJSONString() As String
    Dim fileHandle As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\temp\test.json"
    fileHandle = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As FreeFile
    GetJSONString = Input(LOF(fileHandle), fileHandle)
    Close fileHandle
End Function


Using JSonParser, the required values can be extracted from your sample JSON string as follows;
Sub Test()
    Dim strJSON As String, JSon As Object, id As String, membersValue As String, rolesValue As String
    
    strJSON = "{""schemas"":[""urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"",""urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles"",""urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters""],""id"":""bef561ee-5a1e-420e-a1e\n4-4f624c96af6e"",""meta"":{""resourceType"":""Group"",""created"":""2024-07-25T14:17:53.215Z"",""lastModified"":""2024-08-01T14:31:29.632Z"",""location"":""/api/v1/scim2/Groups/bef561ee-5a1e-420e-a1e4-4f624c96af6e""},""displayName"":""TEAM_TEST"",""members"":[{""value"":""f27dcbb9-df9a-46b2-b23a-3b35d5a8bdff"",""type"":""User"",""display"":""Test_FirstName1 TEST_Familyname1"",""$ref"":""/api/v1/scim2/Users/f27dcbb9-df9a-46b2-b23a-3b35d5a8bdff""}],""urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles"":{""roles"":[{""value"":""PROFILE:t.4:VIEW_USER"",""display"":""VIEW_USER""}]},""urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters"":{""description"":""Team Test""}}"
      
    Set JSon = ParseJson(strJSON)

    id = JSon("id")
    
    membersValue = JSon("members")(1)("value")
    
    rolesValue = JSon("urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles")("roles")(1)("value")

    
    MsgBox "id = " & id & vbCrLf & "members.value = " & membersValue & vbCrLf & "roles.value = " & rolesValue
End Sub



How do I access multiple members like this using loop ? For Each Item In JsonData("Resources") . resources is main Node and multiple Node of my example Json in original post.

-1 is for: Are you going to to keep on editing and changing your sample JSON and changing your minde to select another post as an "answer" instead of posting as a new question

The id key is associated with a single value, not an object or array, so
tempName = JsonData("id")(0)
MsgBox (tempName)   'no parens as noted in BigBen's comment

should be
tempName = JsonData("id")
MsgBox tempName

